# How do I avoid conversion of the array to comma separated string?

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I am using Jmeter 2.4 and am trying to extract the array values and use it for further API calls.

I am using Bean shell Sampler with the below javascript code:

```
var array=${Response};

var Name=new Array();
var Location = new Array();
var ID = new Array();

for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
Name[i] = array[i].Name;
Location[i] = array[i].Location;
ID[i] = array[i].ID
}

vars.put("myName",Name);
vars.put("myLocation",Location);
vars.put("myID",ID);
```

The values of myName and myLocation are stored as string hence making it difficult to use the array values.

How do I avoid conversion of the array to comma seperated string?

Answer (score 0):

If your response is json response, you can process the response as javascript and use it as array. This jmeter-screencast can give you details. http://my.kpoint.com/kapsule/gcc-744b552e-c91e-4db2-9d39-37c6e66f22ac/t/jmeter-tutorial-json-array-extraction

If your response is non-json, you will have to use `regex-extractor` and `foreach controller` to iterate over all values. This jmeter-screencast can give you details. http://my.kpoint.com/kapsule/gcc-1dadaeee-1572-4c83-81fc-8d401cade743/t/jmeter-tutorial-multivalue-regex